# How do I return a different response depending on the form that edited a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and i have an issue.

I have 2 forms which edit the same model, but in the update method I have to give a different JS response depending on the form which submitted.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a `hidden` input field to your form specifying where it comes from.

Then, in your controller, access this field through the `params[:field_name]`.

Create the form by using something like:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :origin, :value => "this_form" %>
```

This will render as something like:

```
<input name="origin" type="hidden" value="foo"/>
```

In your controller, check which value this hidden field had, and use `render` to render your  JS response (or whatever you specifically use). See [Layouts and Rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) for more info.

```
if params[:origin] == "foo"
   render  ...
else
   render ...
end
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two different ways you could go about this:

1. You could put a hidden variable in the form and then check in the controller to see which form was submitted.
2. You could also have two different controller methods to handle the different behavior.

Without knowing more about your code it's hard to say which way would be cleaner.